# High %system and %si cpu time on Linux

Tags: linux

On top and iostat output it seems there is some problem with system and softirq items.

1- Do you think this only caused by ethernet interrupts?

2- I am running netfilter with 60 Mbps traffic on that server. How can I see how much of  %system is used by netfilter and other kernel modules?

3- Time to time, system hangs with OOM condition. However at that moment system has lots of free memory according to sar output. Will higher %system and %idle cause blocking in reaching memory by kernel?

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          34.17    0.00   50.25    0.00    0.00   15.58


Cpu0  : 37.5%us, 18.8%sy,  0.0%ni,  6.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi, 37.5%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  : 33.3%us, 44.4%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi, 22.2%si,  0.0%st


cat /proc/interrupts                              Thu Jul 28 11:55:11 2011

           CPU0       CPU1
  0:  136049409      43332    IO-APIC-edge  timer
  1:          1          1    IO-APIC-edge  i8042
  4:          5          7    IO-APIC-edge  serial
  7:          0          0    IO-APIC-edge  parport0
  8:          2          1    IO-APIC-edge  rtc
  9:          0          0   IO-APIC-level  acpi
 12:          2          2    IO-APIC-edge  i8042
 50:          0          0   IO-APIC-level  uhci_hcd:usb4
 58:          0          0   IO-APIC-level  uhci_hcd:usb7
 66:      80860    4360213         PCI-MSI  ahci
 74:    1698104  274488209   IO-APIC-level  eth1
 98:  157341956    3131716         PCI-MSI  eth4
106:         92         95   IO-APIC-level  HDA Intel
169:          0          0   IO-APIC-level  uhci_hcd:usb3
225:          0          0   IO-APIC-level  ehci_hcd:usb1, uhci_hcd:usb5, uhci_hcd:usb
```

Answer (score 1):

1- What do you mean when you said "ethernet interrupts"?

2- A nearly exact way:

```
$ echo "$(cat /proc/`pidof iptables`/stat | awk '{ print $15 }') * 100 / $(cat /proc/stat | awk '/cpu / { print $4 }')" | bc -l
```

Take a look at `man proc` for more details.

3- Find out which process is eating your RAM with:

```
$ ps -eo pmem,pid,comm | sort -k1rn | head
```

or `atop`, `htop`, ...

Comment: Ethernet interrupt in interrupts OS should deal with while managing ethernet thru drivers. 

None of processes eat ram. Just before oom kernel panic, we have already enough ram space free. (machine has 8 GBram and we have 3gb free at least.